# Getting to my webroot in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WAMP on windows 8.1.
My website is at: D:\program files\wamp\www\WEBSITE

Under website is:

```
/img
/css
Several PHP webpage files including my site header and footer<
/BLOG <-- (wordpress)
```

I'm trying to use my header and footer inside WordPress so I've had to change my header file paths of images to dynamic ones that start from the document root.

When I add `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` it starts from `D:/...` and when I try using `/` in WordPress as webroot it starts from `/BLOG` instead of `/WEBSITE`.

How do I get my root to be `/WEBSITE`?

Answer (score 0):

`get_option('url');` contains the web root directory in wordpress.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo for more options (there are quite a few to choose from..)

or possibly use `home_url()`.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

Answer (score 0):

How about relative from the root?

```
/../img/
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I know that works but I wanted a more dynamic approach to save later heartaches down the road!